# BeautifulSoup output format error: too much whitespace

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

The following code prints abnormally too much whitespace for much of the output.

```
import bs4
import requests


res = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/forum/search.php?do=finduser&userid=126807&contenttype=vBForum_Post&showposts=1')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Here is the part of the output where the formatting becomes a problem:

```
Sportsbooks & The Industry    Service Plays    /   "   >   N   e   w   b   i   e       F   o   r   u   m   /   a   >   /   l   i   >
```

Prettify does not change anything. Any idea why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

If you check source code of website, you will see it has whitespaces around it (Right Click on webpage and click '*Show Page Source*')

I run your code and it prints without newlines and whitespaces.

You can do something like

```
import bs4
import requests


res = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/forum/search.php?do=finduser&userid=126807&contenttype=vBForum_Post&showposts=1')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: prettify changes nothing on my end. On IDLE and pycharm it both shows something like this:

                       i   m   g       s   r   c   =   "   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   f   o   r   u   m   .   s   t   a   t   i   c   -   f   i   l   e   s   .   c   o   m   /   v   b   4   /   i   m   a   g   e   s   /   i   c   o   n   s   /   i   c   o   n   1   .   p   n   g   "       /   &gt;       a       h   r   e   f   =   "   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   w   w   w   .   s   p   o   r   t   s   b   o   o   k   r   e   v   i   e   w   .   c   o

Comment: Wow, that's odd. If you check the source code of the website you will see it has a normal output, no whitespace around characters. May I ask, did you change default fonts on your console or letter spacing between characters?

Comment: Interestingly the output is normal when I tried to run it on windows just now.The whitespacing occurs only on my macbook. I have not changed any default fonts or anything else.

Comment: I'm glad you found some breadcrumbs for your problem. Try to solve it. And welcome to stack overflow :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change to soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') instead of 'lxml'

```
import bs4
import requests


res = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/forum/search.php?do=finduser&userid=126807&contenttype=vBForum_Post&showposts=1')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```